# Changing the Bootstrap Carousel properties

Tags: c1-cms

I'm just starting out looking at Composite C1.  I installed the Open Cph Starter site, and I've seen how to edit, navigate, etc.

Under Media Archive I created a new folder and added my images.  Is there a way to direct the Bootstrap Carousel to cycle through the images in my new folder rather then the Sample Media folder?

Answer (score 1):

Composite's available documentation is pretty thorough and helpful.  I would highly recommend that you read through it all as it will give you a much better idea of how to best use the Composite CMS.  It's a fantastic piece of software with amazing capabilities at customisation and extension, but without knowledge on these topics you may fall short on attempting implementations.

The specific piece of functionality you are targeting is called 'Functions' within Composite.  The Carousel you are talking about is most likely implemented using a 'Function'.  To change the target folder for the 'Function' you would have to open up the Composite Admin interface, edit your page, and then double click on the 'Carousel Function'.  This should display a 'popup' function box editor, with which you can change the target folder selection.

Again this is the basic functionality of Composite described in their documentation.  You can view the documentation for functions here: http://docs.composite.net/Functions

I would highly recommend that you read through all their basic user level documentation.

Comment: There is definitely a higher startup learning curve then I anticipated for someone with zero experience in any CMS.  Because of that, I've gone a different route temporarily.  This is something I want to learn but I needed to have something running faster then I could get over that wall. I do want to get back to this asap. Thank you.